# finiteness of syntomic cohomology of proper varieties over algebraically closed and finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field or a finite field and $X/k$ be a proper variety. Let $G/X$ be a finite flat group scheme. Is $\mathrm{H}^i_\mathrm{syn}(X,G)$ finite for all $i$? (So: are finite flat group schemes for the syntomic topology a suitable analogue of constructible sheaves for the étale topology?)